# Have they changed main thread to use id=2?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-8.0-oreo

I had checks in app, to see if current thread is UI/Main thread ..

```
public static boolean isMainThread(){
    return Thread.currentThread().getId() == 1;
}
```

I noticed, that with Android 8, main thread has name = 'main' & id=2 
So I changed to this:

```
public static boolean isMainThread(){
   return Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper();
}
```

So, did they changed this or is if from a new developer setting? I didn't find nothing on their list of changes
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html

Comment: Don't replicate question tags in the title.

Comment: Nothing in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#getId()) to indicate `getId() == 1` means anything special.

Comment: Are you doing anything special that causes your app to share a process with another app? The check you had is not a good one but it should be `1` in most cases.

Comment: I think they just doesn't know that you using this method to determine main thread.  :)
Just use this common code:
 `getMainLooper().getThread().equals(Thread.currentThread())` 
instead and forget about it.